# Images not loading in my wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, image

I made an html / css mockup of a website and wanted to integrate that static website into wordpress. However, the images are not appearing, and I get the path of the image as the url `localhost/wordpress/logo.png`.

I'm developing it on localhost so the theme in `localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme`
and the images on `localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/`.

I've heard that there's some php code that must be used in each image. Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: There is no any code in your question, it's hard to determine problem.

Comment: if the url of your image is `localhost/wordpress/logo.png` why would you expect to find it in `localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mythemes/images`?  furthermore, thats not where images should go in wordpress, they go in `../wordpress/wp-content/uploads`

Comment: How/where are you inserting the image?

Answer (score 2):

For what you need you have to use something like this:

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png; ?>
```

;)

Comment: It won't let me suggest an edit because it's < 6 chars.  The closing quote is missing.